# Cannot create CLLocation object

Tags: iphone

I am trying to create CLLocation object by using both init methods but its not creating and giving the error. Below is the lines of code:

CLLocationCoordinate2D locCor = userLoc.coordinate;

CLLocation *locloc = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:userLoc.coordinate.latitude longitude:userLoc.coordinate.longitude;

Below is the error i am getting

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_CLLocation", referenced from:

```
  objc-class-ref-to-CLLocation in MyMap.o
```

ld: symbol(s) not found

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Please help, I don't know why its coming. I am using XCode version 3.2.4. Is it something to do with the version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Make sure to `#import` and link against the `CoreLocation` framework.

Comment: I've imported CoreLocation framework in Map.m file but how to link against the CoreLocation framework. I am very new in iphone programming so please explain the things so that i understand and put at right place.

Comment: In the left pane, right-click your target and select `Add existing framework`.  Select `CoreLocation` and it should link correctly.  You will see the framework in the `Link binary with libraries` section of the target.